# Calabash Android: is there a way to carry information across multiple feature files?

Tags: android, automated-tests, bdd, calabash

Is there a way I can get Calabash to retain certain information across `feature files`?

In order to carry information between `scenarios`, I use `@@class_variables`.

Comment: I used Ruby variables inside the step files to store and recall the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ruby's global variables, e.g.

- to set: `$VAR = value`
- to get: `$VAR`

Comment: I've tried to use the `$global_variable` but it did not work.

Comment: I'll try again then reply.